# Lowest Common Ancestor Of A Binary Search Tree failing at a long input case

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-search-tree

### Problem

Given a binary search tree (BST), find the lowest common ancestor (LCA) node of two given nodes in the BST.

According to the definition of LCA on Wikipedia:
“The lowest common ancestor is defined between two nodes p and q as the lowest node in T that has
both p and q as descendants (where we allow a node to be a descendant of itself).”

[Link to Problem Statement](https://leetcode.com/problems/lowest-common-ancestor-of-a-binary-search-tree/description/)

### Logic

To have two queues of the path (traversing based on binary search tree logic) and then traverse both queues, and once you find a discrepancy return previous node. I am aware that you can somehow do it without queues using BST logic, and I will optimize it eventually. But I am just wondering why this is not working.

### Code

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None
import collections
class Solution:
    def lowestCommonAncestor(self, root: 'TreeNode', p: 'TreeNode', q: 'TreeNode') -> 'TreeNode':
        queueForp = collections.deque()
        queueForq = collections.deque()
        phead = root
        qhead = root
        while phead != None:
            queueForp.append(phead)
            if phead == p:
                phead = None
            else:
                if phead.val < p.val:
                    phead = phead.right
                else:
                    phead = phead.left

        while qhead!= None:
            queueForq.append(qhead)
            if qhead == q:
                qhead = None
            else:
                if qhead.val < q.val:
                    qhead = qhead.right
                if qhead.val > q.val:
                    qhead = qhead.left
        print(queueForp)
        print(queueForq)
        prev = None
        while len(queueForp)!= 0 and len(queueForq) != 0:
            currp = queueForp.popleft()
            currq = queueForq.popleft()
            if currp.val == currq.val:
                prev = currp
            else:
                return prev
        
        
        return prev
```

### Issue

It fails on a really large input about 10k

https://imgur.com/a/tvmp9wM

```
p = 5893
q = 3379
```

Output: 41
Expected: 5734
Alternatively, you could try putting this code in leetcode and get the test case.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Replace the `if qhead.val > q.val` by an `else` as you did for the p tree. Otherwise it can happen that you make two steps at once without recording the first step in the deque.

Comment: This fixed it, thank you. but can you explain why? both if statements are opposite and ther will never be a ```if qhead.val ==  q.val``` case?

Comment: ok i get it, if ```if qhead.val < q.val ```  it will be qhead . next and go to the next condition. without appending, is that it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can also replace the second `if` by an `elif` instead to ensure that not two steps happen at once but the `else` will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Recursive Java program to print lca of two nodes

// A binary tree node
class Node {
    int data;
    Node left, right;

    Node(int item)
    {
        data = item;
        left = right = null;
    }
}

class BinaryTree {
    Node root;

    /* Function to find LCA of n1 and n2. The function
    assumes that both n1 and n2 are present in BST */
    Node lca(Node node, int n1, int n2)
    {
        if (node == null)
            return null;

        // If both n1 and n2 are smaller than root, then LCA
        // lies in left
        if (node.data > n1 && node.data > n2)
            return lca(node.left, n1, n2);

        // If both n1 and n2 are greater than root, then LCA
        // lies in right
        if (node.data < n1 && node.data < n2)
            return lca(node.right, n1, n2);

        return node;
    }

    /* Driver code */
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        // Let us construct the BST shown in the above
        // figure
        BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree();
        tree.root = new Node(20);
        tree.root.left = new Node(8);
        tree.root.right = new Node(22);
        tree.root.left.left = new Node(4);
        tree.root.left.right = new Node(12);
        tree.root.left.right.left = new Node(10);
        tree.root.left.right.right = new Node(14);

        // Function calls
        int n1 = 10, n2 = 14;
        Node t = tree.lca(tree.root, n1, n2);
        System.out.println("LCA of " + n1 + " and " + n2
                        + " is " + t.data);

        n1 = 14;
        n2 = 8;
        t = tree.lca(tree.root, n1, n2);
        System.out.println("LCA of " + n1 + " and " + n2
                        + " is " + t.data);

        n1 = 10;
        n2 = 22;
        t = tree.lca(tree.root, n1, n2);
    }
}
```